# Installing ChatJax bookmark on the iPad and iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, safari, bookmarks

I have a 16 GB Apple  Mini iPad using iOS 8.1.2 and am unable to install the bookmark found [**here**](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1088/should-chat-have-tex-support/3297#3297) that renders LaTeX in the Math Stack Exchange chat room. I can't find a browser with a bookmark bar to drag the given link to.

Other users in the room have also been unable to render LaTeX with their iPad and iPhones. Could you provide instructions that someone who is new to Apple products could follow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Safari:

1. Copy this in its entirety to your clipboard on your iOS device:

   ```
   javascript:(function(){if(window.MathJax===undefined){var%20script%20=%20document.createElement("script");script.type%20=%20"text/javascript";script.src%20=%20"http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML%22;var%20config%20=%20%27MathJax.Hub.Config({%27%20+%20%27extensions:%20[%22tex2jax.js%22],%27%20+%20%27tex2jax:%20{%20inlineMath:%20[[%22$%22,%22$%22],[%22\\\\\\\\\\\\(%22,%22\\\\\\\\\\\\)%22]],%20displayMath:%20[[%22$$%22,%22$$%22],[%22\\\\[%22,%22\\\\]%22]],%20processEscapes:%20true%20},%27%20+%20%27jax:%20[%22input/TeX%22,%22output/HTML-CSS%22]%27%20+%20%27});%27%20+%20%27MathJax.Hub.Startup.onload();%27;if%20(window.opera)%20{script.innerHTML%20=%20config}%20else%20{script.text%20=%20config}%20document.getElementsByTagName(%22head%22)[0].appendChild(script);(doChatJax=function(){window.setTimeout(doChatJax,1000);MathJax.Hub.Queue([%22Typeset%22,MathJax.Hub]);})();}else{MathJax.Hub.Queue([%22Typeset%22,MathJax.Hub]);}})();
   ```

   <sup>This is the content of the 'start ChatJax' bookmarklet</sup>
2. Tap the Share button on the toolbar.

   [image]
3. Tap Add Bookmark.

   [image]
4. Tap Save. Ignore whatever content is shown.

   [image]
5. Tap Bookmarks in the toolbar.

   [image]
6. Go back until you reach the root, then tap Favourites.

   [image]
7. Tap Edit on the toolbar.

   [image]
8. Tap the bookmark you've just created.

   [image]
9. Enter a name, erase the contents of the Address field and paste in the bookmarklet.

   [image]
10. Visit the page you want to activate ChatJax, tap Bookmarks, then the bookmarklet.